# Entity Framework Code First: Table Per Hierarchy, doesn't popluate custom discrimiator field

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, discriminator

I am using Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) architecture to work with an existing database schema. When I attempt to use a custom *Discriminator* field name a *DbEntityValidationException*:

> *Property: CourseType Error: The CourseType field is required.*

#### Models

```
public abstract class Course {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CourseType { get; set; }
}
public class OnlineCourse : Course {
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
public class OnsiteCourse : Course {
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

#### Entity Type Configurations

```
public class CourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Course> {
    public CourseMap() {
        this.HasKey(x => x.ID);
        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.CourseType).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
    }
}
public class OnlineCourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OnlineCourse> {
    public OnlineCourseMap() {
        this.Property(x => x.Url).HasMaxLength(500);
    }
}
public class OnsiteCourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OnsiteCourse> {
    public OnsiteCourseMap() {
        this.Property(x => x.Location).HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

#### Data Context

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext {

    public EntityContext(): base("Name=EntityContext") {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CourseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OnlineCourseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OnsiteCourseMap());

        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .Map<OnlineCourse>(x => x.Requires("CourseType").HasValue("Online"))
            .Map<OnsiteCourse>(x => x.Requires("CourseType").HasValue("Onsite"));
    }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

#### Code Executed

```
using (var ctx = new EntityContext()) {
    ctx.Courses.Add(new OnlineCourse() {
        Name = "Online 1",
        Url = "Http://www.online.com"
    });
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have expected an exception like "CourseType cannot be used as discriminator and also be a mapped coulmun" (I evidently don't remember the correct error message). But `CourseType` can't be part of the model as a mapped column when it is a discriminator. The usual pattern is to see it in the mapping configuration only (as you have). Nowhere else.

So it may help if you remove `CourseType` from `Course`. I hope you don't need it for any other logic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.  I have changed my migrations to do a rename to from "CourseType" to  "Discrimiator"

Comment: @Gert: So what's the ending answer here? Like Pauly, I have a preexisting column required to be the descriminator. However it is not part of the model class, only used in Map<T> statements as the required column. Just like http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph advises. None the less, I am seeing a descriminator column created.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer Well, of course there is a discriminator column in the database. It tells EF which entity type to create. If anything is unclear to you, please [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: You should have checked out the link before commenting. It provides an example for explicitly naming the datatype and column name for existing db architecture. I was asking you, an expert, if there is something broken about it because it continues to create a Discriminator column rather than use the existing one named. I did not think a new question was appropriate as it is simply a more detailed answer to this question.

Comment: Well, @one.beat.consumer, you were not very clear about EF insisting on creating a column with the exact name "Discriminator". If you say "a descriminator column" it may as well be a column having the discriminator function. I'm not aware of anything being broken there. It works OK when I re-try the code in the link (which I did read, and already knew).